# R regexp ignore.case and fixed dont work together

Tags: regex, r

I would like to use regexpr("Hello :)","hello :)",fixed=TRUE,ignore.case=TRUE)

but R ignores the ignore.case

Is this possible in R?

Thankyou,

Comment: sorry, im dont understand how i should use /i

Comment: like `"Hello/i"` (I've never EVER coded in R; that's why I'm not getting any more specific; however, what I'm suggesting is pretty universal...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's supposed to do that.  From ?regexpr

```
fixed: logical.  If ‘TRUE’, ‘pattern’ is a string to be matched as
      is.  Overrides all conflicting arguments.
```

Case-insensitive is certainly a conflicting argument.

This works: use a lower-case pattern, and convert the to-be-matched string to lower case:

```
regexpr("hello :)", tolower("Hello :)"),fixed=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thankyou, this helps. I can convert both the strings to lower and then try to match, and it has the effect i wanted.