# grep with special characters

Tags: r, regex, string

I want to find the elements that contains star character in the following vector.

```
s <- c("A","B","C*","D","E*")
grep("*",s)

[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

This is not working. I can understand that since it is a special character.
When I read [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html), I decided to use "\" before star character. But that gave me an error:

```
grep("\*",s)
Error: '\*' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\*"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to escape special characters twice, once for R and once for the regular expression:

```
grep('\\*', s)
```

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to use `fixed=TRUE`

```
grep('*', s,fixed=TRUE)
```

Comment: beware that using this invalidates ignore.case=TRUE (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202600/r-regexp-ignore-case-and-fixed-dont-work-together)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see this link, see https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Why-do-my-regular-expressions-require-a-double-escape-to-get-a-literal-td4437962.html.
As Berend Hasselman mentioned:

> you need the `\\` because the expression between tour quotes is interpreted twice.